# @CreationTimestamp with GraalVM triggers java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.generator.internal.CurrentTimestampGeneration

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, graalvm

I'd like to use the Hibernate annotations `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` in a Spring Boot app, compiled to a Native Image with GraalVM.

When running the image I get, at the bottom of the error stack, `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.generator.internal.CurrentTimestampGeneration.<init>()`.

No issue when running the app with `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Related info:

- I've found another mention of this issue on [Github graalvm-reachability-metadata](https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata/issues/323)
- Seems fixed for Quarkus with [this PR](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/32433)

Answer (score 1):

Add this class:

```java
public class HibernateNativeHints implements RuntimeHintsRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerHints(@NonNull RuntimeHints hints, @Nullable ClassLoader classLoader) {
        try {
            Constructor<CurrentTimestampGeneration> constructor1 =
                    ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(CurrentTimestampGeneration.class,
                                                          CurrentTimestamp.class,
                                                          Member.class,
                                                          GeneratorCreationContext.class);
            Constructor<CurrentTimestampGeneration> constructor2 =
                    ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(CurrentTimestampGeneration.class,
                                                          CreationTimestamp.class,
                                                          Member.class,
                                                          GeneratorCreationContext.class);
            Constructor<CurrentTimestampGeneration> constructor3 =
                    ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(CurrentTimestampGeneration.class,
                                                          UpdateTimestamp.class,
                                                          Member.class,
                                                          GeneratorCreationContext.class);
            hints.reflection().registerConstructor(constructor1, ExecutableMode.INVOKE);
            hints.reflection().registerConstructor(constructor2, ExecutableMode.INVOKE);
            hints.reflection().registerConstructor(constructor3, ExecutableMode.INVOKE);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and reference it in your Spring Boot app, under your existing `@SpringBootApplication`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportRuntimeHints({HibernateNativeHints.class})
```

More docs on [custom hints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.custom-hints).